# Applying PnP Provisioning template with Azure Functions/Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

I'm currently trying to develop a Flow which creates a SharePoint site and then utilizes an Azure Function to provision said site with a selection of libraries and such.

The Flow itself is pretty straight forward, but the bit I'm struggling with is the Azure Function itself, particularly the authentication; It uses a `Connect-PnPOnline` cmdlet, and with our tenant using MFA I've had a bit of difficulty getting around it - I've created a Service Principal User which at the very least has enabled me to connect to the site, but I still can't actually use `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate`, nor any other PnP commands really - when I try and do so, I get:

> "The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."

My Service Principal user has Contribute permissions, and a scope of Sites.FullControl.All, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

See below the Powershell code - I don't think the issue is really arising from there but it can't hurt to show:

```
$requestBody = Get-Content $req -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json

"destination": "SharePointSiteURL"


$destination = $requestBody.destination
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:pass -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:user, $secpasswd)
Connect-PnPOnline -url $destination -AppID $env:user -AppSecret $env:pass
Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate -path "D:\home\site\wwwroot\template.xml"
Out-File -Encoding Ascii -FilePath $res -inputObject "Done $destination"
```

I should note that this is actually my first time using Azure Functions so forgive me if the solution here is quite simple! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referring to MSDN Thread

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/53629265-47da-41f7-b780-35eaba999f73/applying-pnp-provisioning-template-with-azure-functionspowershell?forum=AzureFunctions

This post work https://www.sharepointfire.com/2018/04/sharepoint-online-pnp-site-provisioning-using-flow-and-azure-function/